# Accidently executed wrong command in Linux that delete all files

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I made huge mistake today. Actually i have to delete a specific directory files but by mistakenly i have executed the below command,

```
rm -rf /*
```

I think, It started to delete all file from the root (Suddenly stopped the command after a priod of time).

Now even, i am not able to login in my terminal and mysql database and everything. But I still able to access my websites.

Can anyone suggest how to get back the server to its original condition?

Comment: You should look up on Google `Linux data recovery tools`.

Comment: Definitely start by backing up whatever you can.

Comment: Yep _HUGE_. :( In this moment the data on that computer is erased: it means that its index is erased. The real data is still there and you can try to rescue if not overwritten in the meanwhile. Search for a `Linux data recovery tools`, make a bootable system and see which is the situation. Remember that it can be in part corrupted, so probably you will opt for a full new install of the system trying to save the `/home/*` and some settings. Good luck.

Comment: Did you run it as `root`? If not, you shouldn't have seen any files get deleted if you stopped it in a reasonable period. If you were running as root, you shouldn't do that on a server (IMO: ever) and should start disabling ssh for the root user.

Comment: Disabling SSH wouldn't make any difference for the numerous occasions someone might need to run someone under sudo or su

Comment: Incidentally, most Linux distros these days forbid `rm -rf /` by default,  I wonder if /* is actually handled differently

Comment: Whatever you do to recover from this, there is an additional change you should make: if you're logged in as root, make it a rule and a habit to NEVER use `rm -rf`.  Use `rm -ri` instead.  Especially if you are going to use it with file globbing (`*` and other wildcards).  (I once saw a sysadmin who added the `-rf` flags to any `rm` command he used, just as a habit.  This is a recipe for disaster.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restore from backup... You had a backup, right?

Barring that, if the files you care about are all on non-systems mountpoints (such as /home), then you should be able to reinstall your Linux distro without disturbing them. You will probably need to reinstall/reconfigure system services such as Apache and MySQL.